# Number format error, interior "-" character:

Tags: neo4j

Basically here is the query I want to run against a `Neo4j` database:

```
MATCH (c:Cell)-[ex:EXPRESSES]->(g:Gene) 
WHERE g.geneName = "asb-1" OR g.geneName = "asg-1" 
RETURN g.geneName, c.tsneX, c.tsneY, ex.expr
```

I also tried:

```
MATCH (c:Cell)-[ex:EXPRESSES]->(g:Gene) 
WHERE g.geneName IN ["asb-1", "asg-1"] 
RETURN g.geneName, c.tsneX, c.tsneY, ex.expr
```

But I keep getting the error:

> Neo4jError: number format error: interior "-" character: asb-1

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm seeing that error message in the `integer.js` code for `Integer.fromString()`, which attempts to parse an integer from a string. Can you provide more info on your javascript code? This is likely the culprit. Or are you running this in the Neo4j browser? If so, can you provide the versions of the Neo4j db, browser, and/or Neo4j Desktop (if using the Desktop app)?

Answer (score 1):

I ran the query in the `Neo4j dashboard` and it worked fine. The error was caused further down the road, when `result` object was treated in the `session.run().then()` where I was trying to convert to `integer` value that was of a string type:

```
var convertIntAtIndex = (arr, idx) => {
  arr.map((innerArr) => {
    innerArr[idx] = neo4j.int(innerArr[idx]).toNumber();
    return innerArr;
  });
}
```

Where `innerArr[idx]` was having string values.